# Why are agents able to seize portable resources from different location?

Tags: resources, portability, anylogic

I am trying to simulate a bike-sharing system in which bikes are resources that can be seized and used by customers and then placed in any of several stations after use. I want the customer to pick up bikes from the station they are in, and travel to one of the several other stations available. I have tried to do this using portable resources (which i believe means that resources can only be moved by agents).

When I do this, I find that the customers are able to pick up bikes from stations other than the station they are in. E.g a customer arriving at Station1 is able to pick up a bike that is available in Station 2.

I use one single resource pool, and define GIS-locations for the bikes at the different stations.
Is there a way to restrict agents to picking up resources from their location, and to ensure bikes does not move on their own from 1 station to another, or should I consider a different approach than using 1 resource pool? Additionally, how can i define the position of bikes at the beginning of the simulation?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

/Hal

[Small example with 2 stations, overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1axx.png)

Answer (score 1):

you have too many questions in 1... so i'll give you some hints

1. Each bike should be a resource agent where you hold the current location of it, this will be held by a variable called station that will define what the location is.
2. For a person to grab a bike from its current location, you need to grab a custom agent (customize resource agent in the service block properties) where `unit.station.equals(agent.station)`... assuming that you have in your agent also a station variable that defines what station he's in... otherwise you would need to get the nearest station or something like that
3. You have to ensure that the resources do not go back home after they are released... i think restore agent location on exit has to be unchecked
4. To make all resources start in a location you want, you can select the home location nodes and maybe define the number of resources based on their home locations... many ways to do this, you would have to add more detail

Try all that to start...